Why is there one entry as output in confusion Matrix?
I am applying simple SVM and logistic regression on a simple dataset with 10 samples only. I am trying to print the confusion matrix but it just gives "array([[2]])" as output.
here's the code :
sc = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = sc.fit_transform(X)
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
LR.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=LR.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))//1.0 output
con= confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)  //array([[2]]) ouput
con.shape //(1, 1)
My dataset is a binary classification problem. (0 or 1)

With 10 samples total, yout test probably doesnt even have all possible cases to compute a confusion matrix to start with

No actually its giving a confusion matrix with usual result (2x2) when accuracy is 0.5
